# Learning iOS development on VM machine running Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ios, mac, development

I'm wondering if it's fine to start learning iOS development on VM machine running OS X until I get a Mac computer, will I face any real differences when I start developing on Mac computer?

Comment: It is against Apple's EULA to install or virtualise OS X on anything other than Apple hardware, & I'm afraid this makes it off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about Apple hardware or software within the scope defined in the [help centre](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

Apple's EULA doesn't allow installing OS X on VMs not running on a Macintosh.

Comment: That's the legal part. From a technical point of view, OS X in a VM and running Xcode there is probably fine.